# How to create a list of links that open in an iframe in HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, css

I want to create two vertical divs using HTML5, CSS3 and JQuery. One Div contains URLs and another div contains the content. When I clicked on a link on div1 the related page should show up in div2.

Example of Page 1 being active:

```
   DIV1                        DIV2
 **http://www.yahoo.com**      Yahoo Home Page
   http://www.bing.com
   http://www.google.com
```

Example of Page 2 being active:

```
  DIV1                         DIV2
  http://www.yahoo.com         Bing Home Page
**http://www.bing.com**
  http://www.google.com
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What have you tryed? This smell like *plz-send-me-teh-code* question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/thejase/XWNVn/

### HTML

```
<div id="toc">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<iframe id="content">

</iframe>
```

### CSS

```
#toc { width: 33%; float: left; margin-right: 1%; }
#content{ width: 66%; margin-top: 1px; border: none; outline: 1px solid black; }
```

### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    var $content = $('#content');
    $('#toc a')
        .click(function() {
            $content.attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your valid input. I want to display another page or URL on second div content. 

For Ex :
 Div1 Contains Google|Rrediff|Yahoo
 Div2 should show the respected pages.

If I click on Google , Div2 should display Google page.

Comment: @SrikanthChilukuri: I updated the code to fit your new requirements.  I also better explained your question for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following (make sure all your page links have the .page class):

```
$(function() {
  $('#DIV1').find('a.page').click(function() {
    var html = $(this).html();
    $('#DIV2').html(html);
  });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

HTML5:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Page 1</li>
            <li>Page 2</li>
            <li>Page 3</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="content">Content 1</div>
    <div class="content" style="display: none;">Content 2</div>
    <div class="content" style="display: none;">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS3:

```
.wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
}

nav li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('nav li').click(function() {
    $('.wrapper .content').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

See a working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/RNyg8/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<div id="container"> 
    <div id="left">
    sample
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    sample
    </div>
</div>
```

style for this:

```
#container {
width: 500px;
}
#left {
width: 250px;
float: left;
background-color: #777;
padding: 5px;
}
#right {
width: 250px;
float: right;
background-color: #777;
padding: 5px;
}
```

this will get you two vertical divs. If you wish to add padding, width of container DIV should be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old thread, but in case anyone still looks for an answer, the simpler solution, taken from http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/215340-open-href-into-a-div/

Is to use iframes and add

```
target="content"
```

in the links ("content" being the ID of the iframe):

```
<div id="toc">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="content">Yahoo</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.bing.com" target="content">Bing</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="content">Google</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<iframe id="content">
</iframe>
```